# WordPress: пагинация внутри поста

Tags: php, wordpress

Какую функцию использовать для работы с пагинацией внутри поста, я говорю не о пагинации по записям. То есть мы имеем пост в котором 3 страницы. Я попробовал подобный код, но он ничего не вывел.

```
<?php 
the_posts_pagination( array(
    'mid_size' => 2,
) ); 
?>
```

Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

> пагинация внутри поста

Для этого ничего кодить не нужно - всё есть в ядре.

В контенте достаточно разделить страницы тегом `<!--nextpage-->`
*Кнопка раньше была в редакторе. Можно вывести плагинами типа [tinymce advanced](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) или кодом.*

Только не стоит разбивать один пост на неск страниц. Потом придётся разбираться с каноникалами, урлами и др.  Лучше делать отдельными постами (можно и связывать их - есть плагины для создания серий постов и тп)

Comment: дело в том, что я разрабатываю тему, и мне нужно обработать это. И я не знаю как. Вопрос был не в том как РАЗБИТЬ страницу, а в том как ВЫВЕСТИ пагинацию разбитой страницы.

Comment: Да это в ядре, а не в теме. Уже есть. Если в теме это не работает - значит не правильно подключено ядро. Наиболее частая ошибка - отсутствие `wp_head()` и `wp_footer()`

Comment: Хорошая практика - убеждаться/смотреть на работу функционала в дефлтной теме. Если в кастомной что-то идет не так - значит что-то сделано не то.

Comment: Спасибо, нашел в стандартной теме нужную функцию!